# api_view decorator doesn't work with application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was reading a book on django-rest-framework.

Here is a particular code which doesn't work for me. The request data fields are `None`

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def cars_list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cars = CarModel.objects.all()
        cars_serializer = CarSerializer(cars, many=True)
        return Response(cars_serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.data.get('manufacturing_date'))
        car_serializer = CarSerializer(data=request.data)
        if car_serializer.is_valid():
            car_serializer.save()
            return Response(car_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(car_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Car Model has a field 'manufacturing_date' which i am trying to print

Using `ModelSerializer` to create the `CarSerializer`

If i submit a POST using `curl` without mentioning the "Content Type" which is by default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` , i see the request object is `None`

However , these are the options , where all 3 parsers are supported.

```
curl -iX OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/cars/3
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "Car Detail",
  "description": "",
  "renders": [
    "application/json",
    "text/html"
  ],
  "parses": [
    "application/json",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "multipart/form-data"
  ]
}
```

I was trying to print the request data and i get 'None'
`print(request.data.get('manufacturing_date'))` in `cars_list` function based view.

This works when i set the content type to `application/json`

Using django-1.10 and djangorestframework-3.6.3

After that i checked documentation 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/
and also added 
"parser_class" decorator to include all 3 parsers like below a shown in example:

```
@parser_classes((JSONParser,FormParser, MultiPartParser))
```

But still no luck with "form-urlencoded" data.